# Bind images to a listbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting blank image in listbox, image source in not binding i think...

.xaml code:

```
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" ItemWidth="120" ItemHeight="120"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="b" Click="b_Click_1" Width="120" Height="120" >
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Margin="-10,-10,-10,-10" 
                        x:Name="image1" 
                        Stretch="Fill" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding}"
                    />
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

`
.cs code:

```
         DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\sandeep ams\Documents\Images");
                FileInfo[] file = dir.GetFiles();
                ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                foreach (FileInfo file2 in file)
                {
                    if (file2.Extension == ".JPG" || file2.Extension == ".JPEG" || file2.Extension == ".GIF" || file2.Extension == ".PNG")
                    {
                        list.Add(file2);
                    }
                }
                listBox.ItemsSource = list;
```

here i was trying to bind images to the listbox image source is not binding it is showing  empty images in the listbox.

Comment: You creating an ArrayList of FileInfo objects and expecting it to show you images on UI, do you expect that ? Also without any Binding and Image control.

Comment: And do you really only want to show images with uppercase filename extensions, like `.PNG`?

Comment: @Nitesh Actually there is an Image control with a `Source="{Binding}"` binding. It won't work however.

Comment: See how it works with `list.Add(file2.FullName);` and proper check for filename extensions.

Comment: @Clemens: Oh yes I just saw that. Right it won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this:

```
foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
{
    if (fileInfo.Extension.Equals(".JPG", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
        fileInfo.Extension.Equals(".JPEG", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
        fileInfo.Extension.Equals(".GIF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
        fileInfo.Extension.Equals(".PNG", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        list.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
    }
}
```